# When to use context.filesDir() and context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext().filesDir

Tags: android, native-android

Recently we are seeing a few crashes for our app where exception is

`Fatal Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException /data/user/0/<package-id>/files/folder_name/file_name.jpg : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

**Observations while debugging this issue**

1. `val file = File("${context.filesDir}/$folderName")` this is how app is creating a File object
2. Before accessing this file path app is already calling mkdirs()
3. In logs we are seeing below lines in the logs

`Successfully queried cache dir: /data/user_de/0/<package_id>/code_cache`

`Setting cache dir: /data/user_de/0/<package_id>/code_cache`

user_de: is something I could not understand why/from where it is coming up but when I explored more I got this `context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext().filesDir`

But without this line of code My app was working all okay using `context.filesDir`

Is there anything I am missing here?

**Edit:**

This is the code that produces an exception (only on some devices for example SM-G398FN, SM-G525F, there are some instances where device model is same but we did not get exceptions things went fine we got all needed images)

CameraX implementation for capturing and storing images at context.filesDir

```
private fun takePhoto() {
   val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

   val imagesFolderFile = File(
      context.filesDir, 
      "$folderName${File.separator}$imagesFolderName"
   )

   val photoFile = File(
     imagesFolderFile, 
    "Images/image_timestamp.jpg"
   )

   photoFile.mkdirs()

   val outputOptions = 
     ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        
imageCapture.takePicture(
    outputOptions,
    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
    object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
           override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
            // We are getting exceptions from this line
               Log.e(imageCaptureLogs, exc.message.toString())
               exc.printStackTrace()
           }

           override fun onImageSaved(output: 
               ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
               
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: @blackapps Please check now

Comment: `photoFile.mkdirs()` You created a directory with that name. So after that you cannot create a file with the same name.

Comment: if (!photoFile.getParentFile().exists()) if (!photoFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) return.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue might be related to the creation of the photo file and its parent directories. Specifically, there's an error in the way you are creating the directories for the photoFile.

Instead of using photoFile.mkdirs(), which creates both the file and its parent directories, you should create the parent directories first using File.mkdirs() and then create the file

Comment: If this is the case, then this app should not have worked even once but in fact all our internal testers are not facing any issues related to image capture